# Divs with absolute positioning behaving inconsistently

Tags: css

I'm a bit new to the front end side of things, so forgive me if I'm overlooking something simple.

This is a React application I am building that will have several icons on a screen.  One reads current temperature from a sensor.  I want to display the unit (C or F) in the top right corner, and the sensor reading in the bottom right.

My HTML Code:

```
<div className='app-icon-temp'>
    <div className='icon-temp-current'>00.00</div>
    <div className='icon-temp-unit'>C</div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
.app-icon-temp {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    position:relative;
}
.icon-temp-current {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
}
.icon-temp-unit {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

The first div positions as expected in the bottom right, however, the second div positions in the top left.  I need to move this item to the top right.

What's causing this inconsistency?

Comment: app-icon-temp class is missing the dot in your CSS

Comment: seems like it works for me... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWoLJx

Comment: @Daniel you are right, thanks for pointing that out.  It was missing from the SO question, but not the code I am running

Comment: @MichaelCoker interesting.  Might it be an issue with the React CSS loading?

Comment: Dunno. If you use the inspector, are the classes being applied? And if you click on one of the elements in the inspector, do you see the CSS applied?

Comment: btw, I'm assuming you know there is no `className` attr in HTML - that's react, and that code needs to be in a component to render it as a `class`. If this is static HTML somewhere, you need to change `className` to `class`

Comment: @MichaelCoker The icon-temp-unit class is not being applied to the div when inspected in the developer tools console.  This HTML is also being applied through a render method from React.

Comment: Then that's your problem - your CSS is fine.

Comment: There was a semi-colon after the penultimate class declaration in my code, but not in the question.  I guess this was dropping the following CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

change app-icon-temp to .app-icon-temp
and className to class

If any error still occurs can you please copy the correct code into the question?

```css
.app-icon-temp {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    position:relative;
}
.icon-temp-current {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
}
.icon-temp-unit {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-icon-temp">
    <div class="icon-temp-current">00.00</div>
    <div class="icon-temp-unit">C</div>
</div>
<p>Nothing else is wrong with this code <br> Gotta love those typos huh?</p>
```

Comment: This error was in my question only, and not the original code.  After closer inspection in the developer console, the class is not being applied to the second div for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML (DIV) tags, you have to use "class", not "className":

```css
.app-icon-temp {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    position:relative;
    background: #ddd;
}
.icon-temp-current {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
}
.icon-temp-unit {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='app-icon-temp'>
    <div class='icon-temp-current'>00.00</div>
    <div class='icon-temp-unit'>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand.  I added an edit to the initial question explaining that it's a React application.  In React this is the method in which you apply class names to rendered HTML elements.

Comment: AH, I didn't know that. then it should work, as you can see in my snippet